# Chartjs datalabels not showing correct values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, chart.js, razor-pages

I want to display the datalabels on the top of each bar, i have done this with Chartdatalabels plugin. But instead of showing the value, it is displaying the object as shown below and i only need o display the datalabels for second graph (highlighted in red)
[image]

The code which i am using is given below.I have registered the datalabels plugin.

```
var WeeklyData = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.UDTSLDDailyPVA.ToList()))
        console.log(WeeklyData);


        let weeklylabels = [...new Set(WeeklyData.map((x) => x.Day))];
        console.log(weeklylabels);
        
        let weeklydatasets = (WeeklyData.map((y) => y.TotalActual));
        console.log(weeklydatasets);
        
       
        var barChartDataWeekly = {
            labels: weeklylabels,
            datasets: [{                
                data: WeeklyData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 154, 221, 1)'                    
                ]
            }],
        };

        var YieldData = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.UDTSLDMonthlyYield.ToList()))
        var AnnotationValue = YieldData[0].YieldTarget;
        console.log(AnnotationValue);
        let yieldlabels = [...new Set(YieldData.map((x) => x.Day))];

        var yieldDataMonthly = {
            labels: yieldlabels,
            datasets: [{                
                data: YieldData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 154, 221, 1)'                    
                ]
            }],
        };

        Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctxUPHHistory = document.getElementById('barChartUPHHistory').getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctxUPHHistory, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartDataWeekly,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    parsing: {
                        xAxisKey: 'Day',
                        yAxisKey: 'TotalActual'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize:20
                                //// Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                //callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                                //    return value + '%';
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            var ctxYieldHistory = document.getElementById('barChartYieldHistory').getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctxYieldHistory, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: yieldDataMonthly,                
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    parsing: {
                        xAxisKey: 'YM',
                        yAxisKey: 'YieldActual'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: false,
                                stepSize: 20,
                                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                                    return value + '%';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        datalabels: {
                            anchor: 'end',
                            align: 'end',
                            labels: {
                                value: {
                                    color: 'white'
                                }
                            },
                            formatter: (val) => {
                                return val + '%';
                            }
                        },
                        annotation: {
                            annotations: {
                                line: {
                                    type: 'line',
                                    yMin: AnnotationValue,
                                    yMax: AnnotationValue,
                                    borderWidth: 2,
                                    borderColor: 'white'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: If you want to have datalabels only for one chart and not for the other, don't register the plugin globally (that is, remove `Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);` line), but locally, adding `plugins: [ChartDataLabels]` at the top of the configuration object for the chart that uses them - see [registration](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration) in the plugin docs.

Comment: If the `value` of the label is an object, use the info in the [data transformation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#data-transformation) paragraph. In practice, in the datalabels `formatter` use `console.log(value)` to see the actual structure of the `value` object, identify the `keyForActualValue` under which the value you want to present at datalabel is, and then replace `return value + '%';` with `return value.keyForActualValue + '%';`

Comment: @Kikon, Thank you for your help.The issue has been solved with your guidance.

Comment: Hi @Teena, glad to see you found the answer. You may [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and next accept the answer to resolve it once available. Thanks.

Comment: @Yong Shun, Sure, i will add the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with @Kikon's guidance. Please find the answer below :

```
        var ctxYieldHistory = 
        document.getElementById('barChartYieldHistory').getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctxYieldHistory, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: yieldDataMonthly,
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: 'YM',
                    yAxisKey: 'YieldActual'
                },
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        top: 40,
                        bottom: 0
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: false,
                            stepSize: 20,
                            // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                            callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                                return value + '%';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    datalabels: {
                        anchor: 'end',
                        align: 'end',
                        labels: {
                            value: {
                                color: 'white'
                            }
                        },
                        formatter: function (value, context) {
                            console.log(value.YieldActual);
                            return value.YieldActual + '%';
                        }
                    },
                    annotation: {
                        annotations: {
                            line: {
                                type: 'line',
                                yMin: AnnotationValue,
                                yMax: AnnotationValue,
                                borderWidth: 2,
                                borderColor: 'white',
                                borderDash: [10, 5]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```